# Accessing parameters from one loop in nested loop Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 3 loops

```
$.each(results.doc, function(index, element){
                for(var i=0; i < self.options.maxMatches; i++){
                    var RealCategory = this.data[0]['realcategories'][i];
                    var realcategoryName = RealCategory.name;
                    for(var j = 0; j< RealCategory.tournaments.length; j++){
                        var tournamentName = RealCategory.tournaments[j].name
                        self.append('<li>' + realcategoryName+' / '+i+' - '+tournamentName+' / '+j+' </li>');
                    }
                };
            });
```

In `self.options.maxMatches` i decide how much results will i show in HTML. Let's say `self.options.maxMatches=10`. Problem appears when `RealCategory.tournaments.length>0`. Than i get results from third and second loop. If third for loop get me 2 results i get i my HTML 10 + 2 results, but what i wan't it's just 10 results.

Comment: I can only see two `for` loops. Did you count the `each` as the third?

Comment: Yes, i mean each is one loop and two for loops, sorry if it's not understandable written.

Comment: @k-nut, `$.each` is essentially a loop wrapper. It loops through the elements in the first parameter and executes the function on each one so it is technically a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want at most a `maxMatches` number of `<li>`s (or `tournaments`), then you'll want to keep a separate counter from either indexer and exit the loops based on that.

```
var limit = self.options.maxMatches;
$.each(results.doc, function () {
    // ...
    for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
        // ...
        for (var j = 0; j < RealCategory.tournaments.length; j++) {
            // ...

            limit--;
            if (limit <= 0) {
                // exit iterator `function`, interrupting both `for` loops
                // `false` to instruct jQuery to not continue looping
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

`maxMatches` is currently only limiting the number of `realcategories`. But, each of those has an unknown number of `tournaments` each (possibly `0`, possibly `5`, etc.).

2 possible scenarios:

```
i               | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | (e.g. maxMatches = 5)
tournaments (A) | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 1 | (total = 7)
tournaments (B) | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | (total = 2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, for exlplaining and showing me how to do this. Only thing is it should be for (var j = 0; j < RealCategory.tournaments.length; j++) instead of i++. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

try this, this is a quick fix. I incremented ur variable 'i' in the inner loop (though this code can be written in a lot better ways)

```
$.each(results.doc, function(index, element){
                for(var i=0; i < self.options.maxMatches; ){
                    var RealCategory = this.data[0]['realcategories'][i];
                    var realcategoryName = RealCategory.name;
                    for(var j = 0; j< RealCategory.tournaments.length; j++){
                        i++;
                        var tournamentName = RealCategory.tournaments[j].name
                        self.append('<li>' + realcategoryName+' / '+i+' - '+tournamentName+' / '+j+' </li>');
                    }
                };
            });
```

Comment: i already try that and not working. If i enter 10 results i get 7. Could you please show how could be written in a better ways? I would like to learn write better code.

Comment: refer to @jonathan Lonowski's solution above.. you can use a limit flag like that. You can also modulate the json/array structure of your results. From the code it looks it could use some restructuring.

Comment: Thank you @Taran J, i am sure it could be use a lot of restructuring. I am still learning programming, that is why i am thankful for every hint or solution from you guys.